# Site login does not persist

Tags: browsers

When trying to post a comment in some tech forums using Tor, I log in (accepted), type my comments and try to submit them.
I am then taken to the login window where I am required to log in again and then I am presented with a blank comment window where I have to post my comments again. :-/
This loop continues as long as I care to keep doing it.
I used to be able to log in and post while using tor.
What's up?

Comment: What forums are affected by this?

Comment: http://archive.totalsem.com/forums/ is one

Answer (score 1):

You might find the TrackHostExits option useful:

> This option is useful if you frequently connect to sites that will expire all your authentication cookies (i.e. log you out) if your IP address changes.

Comment: It appears that, like all other things Tor, the way to use that option is shrouded jargon-ese that is indecipherable to someone with a lay education in computers. Thanks anyway but I'll just remove Tor from my system. I really was expecting better responses from this forum.

Comment: Dear Sam Blivet, Sorry to hear that. In my own humble wisdom, good thing are hard to get. If one really wants to learn somthing, one should be persistent and patient. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The site you are using might have some kind of time out. So if you need some time to write your comment, maybe the session ran out and the site thinks you are a new user. Maybe they also register what IP a user has and if it changes they think it is a new user.

Two things may help you:

1. For Mozilla's Firefox there is the plugin [It's all text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/). It allows you to enter a text for comments, forum posts etc. in an editor. So an extra program opens, you edit the text there and upon saving the comment field is automatically updated. Using this plugin has the advantage that the text is saved in a temporary file in your harddrive. So if you have to login again, you can take the text and copy it into the window.
2. As Roya [wrote](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/1624/88) there is an option for Tor. So locate your `torrc` and insert a line with the text `TrackHostExits archive.totalsem.com,example.com`. Whenever you're visiting `archive.totalsem.com` or `example.com` Tor will try to use the same exit relay. So you are visiting the site with the same IP address and you session remains.